# what is the "email analysis"? and how can I enable it?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

whiten MSDN article about [Plan for My Sites](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262500.aspx) ... i found the following:

> If email analysis is enabled, users can also find people by using email analysis in Outlook 2013. Colleague suggestions are imported from Outlook if you are using Office Outlook 2007 email.

what is the "email analysis"? and how can I enable it?

Answer (score -1):

Allow analysis of sent emails to identify people you commonly email and subjects you commonly discuss, and upload this information to the default SharePoint Server.

To enable it follow these steps:

To allow or block email suggestions for keywords in Outlook:

1. Open Outlook.
2. On the File menu, click Options > Advanced .
3. Under Other , in the Allow analysis of sent emails to identify
   people you commonly email and subjects you commonly discuss, and
   upload this information to the default SharePoint Server option, do
   either of the following:

   > To allow email suggestions in your personal site , select the check
   >   box.
   >
   > To block email suggestions in your personal site , clear the check
   >   box.

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/View-and-set-up-your-profile-b8ff9f7c-b9fc-4171-be3f-b517a434497a

Comment: for where this emails will sent? for which frame?